# xcode4 group folder to bundle sub directory

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode4

If I create a group of images as resource files in xcode4 right menu, How can I :

-automaticly create this group name as sub-directory in resource path, with all the files in it?

-get all the names of files in that folder ?

thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think Xcode can do these things.

In addition, Xcode doesn't suggest to make a lot of folders in your project folder. The default folders created by template is good enough. You do NOT need to manager them by yourself.

But if you insist on managing folders in your project by yourself, you should do it with Finder and then add them to Xcode as References (Make sure "Create groups for any added folders" is selected).